# Running 2 custom actions at the same time gives error

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have 2 custom actions running at the same time. How do I schedule them to run after the 1st one has finished. Here is my code:

```
<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit1" FileKey="InterUMIEXE" ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit1" Before="InstallFinalize">$InterUMIEXE=3</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit2" FileKey="Python" ExeCommand="" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action ="StartAppOnExit2" Before="InstallFinalize">$Python=3</Custom>     
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit1" Before="InstallFinalize">$InterUMIEXE=3</Custom>
 <Custom Action ="StartAppOnExit2" After="StartAppOnExit1">$Python=3</Custom>     
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Try that and see if it works..:)

Comment: Try scheduling them after `InstallFinalize` as they are immediate custom actions and run a verbose log to see if they are getting executed. Also you have set `Impersonate="no"` which means you want your custom actions to run with elevated privileges, immediate custom actions cannot do this you would need them to be deferred.

Comment: they are both deferred CA's actually. Was trying to experiment with different options just to see if something was working !! And yes , they do get executed , but the problem is , they get executed simultaneously , which is the problem. I want them to get executed after 1 finishes with the installation , otherwise simultaneous executions gives error !! Hope you understood my problem.

Comment: What does the verbose log say? I am using the exact same code as yourself and it is working, are you sure the conditions are being met?

Comment: Use ORCA to see execution sequence of the custom actions

Comment: ORCA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx